# PHP 7.0 with IMAP and MAILPARSE on MAC OS

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew, php-7

On [31st of March Homebrew moved some of their formulas around](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/). For this reason I can't find a way to make my PHP 7 work with the following extensions:

```
mailparse
imap
```

I have tried many examples found on the internet, such as

- brew install php70 --with-imap
- brew install -s php70 --with-imap
- brew install php70-imap

*not mentinoning the `brew update, brew upgrade, brew tap etc...`*

But none of them seems to work as brew php does not work with options anymore.

I had even less options trying to install without homebrew, as I am using `nginx` in my computer, not `apache`.

Does any one had this problem and was able to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

After some troubleshooting, it finally worked..... That's how I did:

First I installed the following formulas:

```
brew install imap-uw
brew install openssl
```

After that, I downloaded the same version of the pho is running in my computer on http://php.net/downloads.php (saved it in Downloads folder).

In terminal I did.

```
cd ~/Downloads/php-7.0.29/ext/imap
./configure --with-imap=/usr/local/Cellar/imap-uw/2007f --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl
make
```

where `/usr/local/Cellar/` is the path where the formula imap-uw is installed.

**P.S** this configure file does not accept `--with-openssl` or `--with-openssl-dir` or `+openssl`. I waist a lot of time trying that.

it created a folder `modules/` with the `imap.so` file inside.

Then I created a folder and moved the imap file to inside it

```
mkdir /usr/local/opt/php70-imap
mv modules/imap.so /usr/local/opt/php70-imap/imap.so
```

After that just add the extension to the `php.ini` file

```
extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-imap/imap.so"
```

Restart the server and imap will work fine!

For *mailparse* I had to use pecl.

First I followed this tutorial https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/

After `pecl` was installed properly in my computer, I ran the following code:

```
cd
pecl download mailparse
tar -xvf mailparse-3.0.2.tgz 
cd mailparse-3.0.2/
phpize
./configure
sed -i 's/#if\s!HAVE_MBSTRING/#ifndef MBFL_MBFILTER_H/' ./mailparse.c
make
mkdir /usr/local/opt/php70-mailparse
sudo mv modules/mailparse.so /usr/local/opt/php70-mailparse/mailparse.so
```

I got the piece of code above here https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser . However the line `sed -i 's/#if\s!HAVE_MBSTRING/#ifndef MBFL_MBFILTER_H/' ./mailparse.c` has not worked properly. I ran `make` anyways and it worked.

After that just add the extension to the `php.ini` file

```
extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-mailparse/mailparse.so"
```

Comment: Where is the **modules/** folder created?

Comment: Same folder where you run the pecl @BryanLamtoo

Comment: This is what I did to overcome the sed error:

sed -i '' 's/\#if\s!HAVE_MBSTRING/#ifndef MBFL_MBFILTER_H/' ./mailparse.c